# Trying to get a 10uS pulse width to fire an SCR using a PIC16F884

Tags: microchip, induction-motor, timing, scr, single-phase

I have the circuit built and running but I need to shorten the pulse width of the SCR. I am using a PIC16F884 running at 16MHz.  I am using a half wave to control a device. When I use a for next loop, my on and off time is around 660uS, and if I try to reduce the number, I will have missing firing pulse. The following code has the for next loop in it.

```c
void init_int(void) {
    INTEDG = 0; //1; // Interrupt is on falling edge of int pin
    TRISB0 = 1; // Set RB0 as input
    ANS12 = 0; // Set RB0 as digital
    IOCB0 = 1; // 0; // Interrupt on change
    WPUB0 = 0; // Pull-up disable
    nRBPU = 1; // Port b pull-up are disable
    GIE = 1; // enable global interrupts
    PEIE = 1; // Enable Peripheral Interrupt
    INTE = 1; // enable interrupt flag
    INTF = 0; // Clear external interrupt flag
    T0IE = 0; // Disables the Timer0 interrupt
    ei(); // enable global interrupt 
}

void __interrupt() HardW() {
    if (INTCONbits.INTF == 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < speed_val; x++) { // phase angle
        }
        INTCONbits.INTF = 0;
        Gate = 1; // turn SCR on 
        for (x = 0; x < 165; x++) { // 165 = 660uS Positive pulse width 
         } 
        Gate = 0; // turn Scr off

    } else
        INTCONbits.INTF = 0;
}
```

if I use the following code with TMR0 I will not get 60 hz firing pulse.

```c
void __interrupt() HardW() {
   T0IE = 1;
    if (INTCONbits.INTF == 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < speed_val; x++) { // phase angle
        }
        INTCONbits.INTF = 0;
        Gate = 1; // turn SCR on 
        while (T0IE = T0IF) {
            T0IF = 0;
            T0IE = 0;
        }
        Gate = 0; // turn Scr off

    } else
        INTCONbits.INTF = 0;
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I think you have a coding bug here: `while (T0IE = T0IF)`. Do you mean `while (T0IE == T0IF)` instead? (`==` instead of `=`).